# how can I transform 6 audio channels into one 5.1 channel with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a pro-res file which has 6 mono audio channels.
here's the ffmpeg console:

```
    :\test-remapping>ffmpeg -i MelleParadis_PART1_CONSTANTE.mov
ffmpeg version N-60106-ge6d1c66 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 22 2014 22:01:26 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 63.100 / 52. 63.100
  libavcodec     55. 49.100 / 55. 49.100
  libavformat    55. 25.101 / 55. 25.101
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.2 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.3 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.4 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.5 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.6 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'MelleParadis_PART1_CONSTANTE.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2013-11-27 18:58:26
  Duration: 00:07:34.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 117742 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le, 1920x1080,
 113098 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-27 18:58:26
      handler_name    : Gestionnaire dıalias Apple
      timecode        : 01:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16,
 768 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-27 18:58:26
      handler_name    : Gestionnaire dıalias Apple
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16,
 768 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-27 18:58:26
      handler_name    : Gestionnaire dıalias Apple
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16,
 768 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-27 18:58:26
      handler_name    : Gestionnaire dıalias Apple
    Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16,
 768 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-27 18:58:26
      handler_name    : Gestionnaire dıalias Apple
    Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16,
 768 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-27 18:58:26
      handler_name    : Gestionnaire dıalias Apple
    Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16,
 768 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-27 18:58:26
      handler_name    : Gestionnaire dıalias Apple
    Stream #0:7(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-27 19:03:46
      handler_name    : Gestionnaire dıalias Apple
      timecode        : 01:00:00:00``
```

I would like to transform them into one 5.1 audio channel

I try this line of code:

```
D:\test-remapping>ffmpeg -i "MelleParadis_PART1_CONSTANTE.mov" -c copy -c:a ac3 -map 0 mlle5.1.mov
```

the console replies "NOT ENOUGH SPACE" and stop...
of course there's still some space in my hard drive...
How could I map all the 6 mono streams into 5.1 ? 
thanks in advance.
pauline

Answer (score 5):

from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation

```
ffmpeg -i front_left.wav -i front_right.wav -i front_center.wav -i lfe.wav -i back_left.wav -i back_right.wav \
-filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a] amerge=inputs=6" output.wav
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It's not really a solution; I have mymovie.mov which has 6 audio streams, so 7 tracks. I would like two track: one for video and one 5.1 track for audio...
I can't figure out how to make this routine...

Comment: @user2216280 Please update your question with some information about your input so we can update the answer. The complete `ffmpeg` console output of `ffmpeg -i mymovie.mov` will suffice.

Comment: you can extract your audio channels and then make 5.1 using map option http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options